# Is the mean of the Weierstrass function defined?

Tags: functions, means

The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is an example of a function that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

My question is whether the mean $\bar{f}$ of the Weierstrass function $f(x)$ can be found. Where the [mean of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) is defined as:

$$\bar{f}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx.$$

As a follow up question if the mean exists does the variance of this function exist?

Comment: Sure, it's a continuous function so it has an integral on a finite interval, and so does its square. But what does it matter?

Comment: @Ian I was thinking about an analogy with white noise. The Weierstrass function is self-similar so we can zoom in without any loss of complexity. Continuous time white noise is also self-similar and is described as having [infinite variance](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/variance-of-white-gaussian-noise). I guess I am wondering whether all self-similar functions have infinite variance since zooming in does not cause them to become smoother.

Comment: White noise is not self-similar. Its time integral (a random continuous nowhere differentiable function) is.

Comment: The function given in the link has period $2$, and its mean is obviously $0$.